# No HTML suggestions in Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I've download [the latest Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) and am trying to write some HTML code. For example, `<div>, <a>, <p>` tags. However, there are no HTML suggestions in Visual Studio Code:

[image]

I've read [this article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html) and it says:

> Visual Studio Code provides basic support for HTML programming out of
>   the box.

However, I've tried to install HTML extension:

[image]

In addition, I've turned on HTML5 suggestion in `settings.json` file:

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Light",
    "workbench.activityBar.visible": true,
    "editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd",
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "html.suggest.html5": true,    
}
```

Nevertheless, HTML, CSS suggestion does not work.

What can I do to code with suggestions?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think the issue is that Visual Studio Code is not detecting the file type correctly. If you notice in these pictures, vscode has correctly detected that I am writing a html file by the icon `<>` beside the file name and the language indicator in the bottom right of the screen.

[image: File Icons]
[image: Language indicator]

The language indicator most likely says `plain text` in your case. Click on it and a menu should appear at the top centre of the screen. Then try the following:

1. Enabling `Auto Detect`. I think this will be the first option.
2. Selecting `Configure File Association for '.html'...`
3. 2 can also be accomplished by adding

   > "files.associations": { "*.html": "html" }

   to your settings.

**OR just add to `settings.json (File -> Preferences -> Settings)`:**

```
{
     // Configure file associations to languages (e.g. "*.extension": "html"). These have 
     //precedence over the default associations of the languages installed.
     "files.associations":  { "*.html": "html" },
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I couldn't understand why VS Code was setting all my HTML files to plain text every time they were opened. I looked in settings.json and saw that whoever was using the computer before me (work sharing) has set the  *.html association to Emmet. I'll remember to check here now, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Just go to "File -> Preferences -> Settings"

Search for "Associations"

[image: Check this image]

Comment: This seems like a shortened version of the longer and more detailed answer that was accepted. Please make sure your answer is unique. I also suggest you read [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Go to

<kbd>File</kbd>   <kbd>></kbd>  <kbd>Preferences</kbd>  <kbd>></kbd>  <kbd>settings</kbd>  <kbd>></kbd>   <kbd>Extensions</kbd>  <kbd>></kbd>   <kbd>Emmet</kbd>

Then click on

```
( C:\Users\Code\User\settings.json ) #
```

for reference

Add the following code:-

```
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
"files.associations": {"*html":"html"},
```

Save the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you working with .php file and you trying to autocomple html emmet suggestion you need to disable php langauge from "emmet.excludeLangauge" presented in settings.json (user settings) file.

[image: Like this]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).