# Visual Studio Code don't recognize HTML file

Tags: html, django, visual-studio-code

I am learning to build a Website on Python Django, but when I create a HTML file in VS code, this Editor don't recognize this file. You can see in following picture. I don't know how to solve this problem. Pls help me if you know, thank you very much
[image]

Comment: What do you expect to see? VSC-Emmet has starter code via `!` and `!!!`

Answer (score 0):

- Try to install any HTML extension
- Turn on HTML5 suggestion in settings.json file:

  "html.suggest.html5": true

Follow this post

[No HTML suggestions in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49842125/no-html-suggestions-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0):

Note that in the bottom right-hand corner of your screen, the document language is Python Django, but if you click that and change the language to HTML, you will get HTML language features.

if necessary, sometimes it can be useful to compose a document in a side-by-side window that has the language type you need, to get the hinting and auto completion features, and then copy that into the adjoining document.

Answer (score 0):

After installing and activating Django extension;
File - Preferences - Settings
Then find "Emmet:Include Languages" (You can use CTRL + F for that)

After that arrange "Item" and "Value":

Item = django-html

Value = html

Then click OK

In this way, it will be solved I guess